# Can't see text that I'm editing in a chat room

Tags: bug, design, edits, chat

I went to edit my text in a chat room, but I was not able to see the text while trying to edit it. I am only able to see it while I highlight it.

- Using Windows 7
- Using Google Chrome
- Using "Grammarly" Google Chrome Add-on (I don't know if it can affect it.)

Examples:

[image: Chat room editing text]

[image: Only see the text when highlighted]

Comment: Which chat room?

Comment: @Shog9 All of them

Comment: Definitely can't reproduce then. Try disabling the extension and report back to us.

Comment: @Shog9 Disabling the extension works! But, I really want to use it, can you fix it if you currently have that extension on?

Comment: If the extension is overriding the styles without taking the background color into consideration... That's really on that extension. They should fix that.

Comment: I'll send a bug report to them